# Rearanging Data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I am trying to rearrange a data set and then sort it on multiple variables. For example, right now I have something that looks like this:

```
ID   Name          Class 1         Class2       Monday 7-8         Monday 8-9  
1    Brad          Chem            Bio          Monday 7-8         NA
2    Charlene      Acct            NA           NA                 Monday 8-9
3    Carly         Philosophy      Physics      NA                 NA
4    Jess          Chem            Acct         Monday 7-8         Monday 8-9
```

And sort the data like this:

```
Class               Monday 7-8           Monday 8-9
Acct                Jess                 Charlene, Jess
Bio                 Brad                 NA
Chem                Brad, Jess           Jess
Philosophy          NA                   NA
Physics             NA                   NA
```

I have tried separating all of the variables into different spreadsheets and then merging them, but I cant figure out how to sort the name based on both class and time and it is proving incredibly difficult to figure out. The actual database is composed of about 70 different time options with 80 different people and 150 different class names (chem, bio, etc), so I cant go in and create this individually

Comment: Share the code you are using to sort your dataset.

Comment: I may have deleted all of it in a fit of frustration and no longer have access to it. It was very bad anyways and got nowhere near to the solution that I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a `tidyr` solution:

```
df1 %>%
  gather(class_col,Class,'Class.1','Class2') %>%
  filter(!is.na(Class)) %>%
  gather(date_col,date,'Monday.7.8','Monday.8.9') %>%
  group_by(Class,date) %>%
  summarize(Name = paste(Name,collapse=", ")) %>%
  spread(date,Name) %>%
  select(-`<NA>`)

# # A tibble: 5 x 3
# # Groups:   Class [5]
#          Class `Monday 7-8`   `Monday 8-9`
#   *      <chr>        <chr>          <chr>
#   1       Acct         Jess Charlene, Jess
#   2        Bio         Brad           <NA>
#   3       Chem   Brad, Jess           Jess
#   4 Philosophy         <NA>           <NA>
#   5    Physics         <NA>           <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some base R code for this task:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    name=c("Brad", "Charlene", "Carly", "Jess"),
    class1=c("Chem", "Acct", "Philosophy", "Chem"),
    class2=c("Bio", NA, "Physics", "Acct"),
    monday7.8=c("monday7.8", NA, NA, "monday7.8"),
    monday8.9=c(NA, "monday8.9", NA, "monday8.9"),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
classes <- c("Chem", "Acct", "Philosophy", "Physics")
times <- c("monday7.8", "monday8.9")
ret <- expand.grid(class=classes, time=times, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
one_alloc <- function(cl, tm, dat) {
    idx <- which(!is.na(dat[,tm]) & (dat[,"class1"]==cl | dat[,"class2"]==cl))
    if(length(idx)>0) return(paste(dat[idx,"name"], collapse=", ")) else return(NA)
}
one_alloc <- Vectorize(one_alloc, vectorize.args=c("cl", "tm"))
ret[,"names"] <- one_alloc(cl=ret[,"class"], tm=ret[,"time"], dat=dat)
ret <- reshape(ret, timevar="time", idvar="class", direction="wide")
ret
```